# Passing variable, pushViewControll

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I'm trying to build a simple Navigation Controller with a map function. I'm trying to take two variables from the Root view to the Detail view. One have the label and have the longitude.

I get the values from the Root to the Detail'd view but in the log it says this:

- 2012-04-12 14:38:41.331 Map[80073:11603] long: 0.000000
- 2012-04-1214:38:41.331 Map [80073:11603] Label
- 2012-04-12 14:38:41.331 Map[80073:11603] long: 62.375702

Where long is the longitude and label the variable which should be the label. I'm only passing one 'long' variable but always get the 0.00000 first anyway which makes the map show a wrong location and the label won't show anything at all..

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong for hours but can't seem to find anything in the code or on the web so any help is very much appreciated.

RootViewController.m:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


            NSString *term = @"Label";
            float longi1 = 100.102321;


 DetailViewController *svc = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 

            //send properties to your view controller

             svc.term = term;
            svc.longi = longi1;

            //push it to the navigationController
           [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
            [svc release];
            svc = nil;

        }
```

DetailViewController.m:

```
        - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

 NSLog(term);
        NSLog(@"long: %f", longi);
        coor.text = term; 
    float lati = 65.12414;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {.latitude = lati, .longitude = longi};
        MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  0.5, .longitudeDelta= 0.5};
        MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};
        [mapView setRegion:region];
        [self.view addSubview:mapView];  
    }
```

Comment: You show 'long' being printed twice but only one NSLog() statement for 'long'.  Where is the other one coming from?

Comment: I think that this (first printout) is the source of the problem, check your pre-`viewdidload` methods (like `init`, `viewWillLoad` etc) and verify that you do not change/set the property there. The problem with that scenario of course is why your map shows the wrong thing since your last printed value seems ok...

Comment: Can you change the title to something that more accurately describes the problem please.

Comment: @Philip I have no idea where the other one is coming, that's part of the problem I suppose

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `-initWithNibName:bundle:` loads the view in to memory and causes `-viewDidLoad` to be invoked before you assign the longitude.

Try moving the code in `-viewDidLoad` to `-viewWillAppear`

Comment: Thanks so much man! Now it only shows one log entry for the longitude but now it doesn't affect the label or the mapView when I run it